# Combinatorics: Ways to pick 5 card poker hands to get the ace of spaces and another the ace of hearts.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, poker

Please someone explain to me how to do the following problem:

> How many different 5 card poker hands can you get where one of the cards must be the ace of spades and another the ace of hearts?

My answer is $$\binom{52}{4} + \binom{51}{3}$$ because there are total of $52$ cards with $4$ aces. There are $\binom{52}{4}$ ways to choose the ace of spade. After we choose the ace of spade, there are total of $51$ cards left in the deck with $3$ aces. There are $\binom{51}{3}$ ways to choose the ace of hearts. Then we add them both.

**Is my answer right?**

Comment: There is only one way to pick the ace of spades and only one way to pick the ace of hearts.

Comment: The Rule of Addition is that : the count of an *union* of *disjoint* events equals the sum of the count of the events.  This is not applicable here. You want to find the count of an *intersection* of *non-disjoint* events.

Comment: There is not 4 ways to chose the ace of spades

Answer (score 1):

Once you have selected the ace of spades and the ace of hearts, you have 50 remaining cards from which you choose 3 to complete the 5-card hand. Thus the total number of ways is simply
$$\binom{50}{3}.$$

Comment: What is a hand in Poker?

Comment: It is 5-cards, Vada Curry, as specified in *your* opening post.

Comment: A hand is simply a collection of cards from the deck. A card player usually holds the cards in their hand when playing a game, hence the collection is called a hand. So another way to state this problem is "How many ways can you select 5 cards from a 52 card deck that contain both an ace of spades and an ace of hearts?"

Answer (score 0):

There is only one ace of spades and one ace of hearts
Take the other three from the 50 remaining

$$\frac{\binom{2}{2} \binom{50}{3}} {\binom{52}{5}} = 1 / 132.6 \approx 0.0075414781
 $$

Comment: The question does not ask for a probability.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig How many different is not a probability?  Good day.

Comment: It is not.  What you are supposed to calculate is the number of hands (your numerator), not the probability of obtaining such a hand.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Including a denominator makes it wrong?

Comment: Yes.  The number of outcomes is the number of different hands that contain an ace of spades, an ace of hearts, and three other cards, which, as you found, is $$\binom{2}{2}\binom{50}{3}$$  The probability is the number of outcomes divided by the number of all possible outcomes, which, in this case, is $$\binom{52}{5}$$ since the hands are being selected from a deck with $52$ cards.